# Simple exercise with differentials

Tags: calculus, variational-analysis

Given the diferentials
$$
\begin{equation}
d'Q=K(x-x')d'x
\end{equation}
$$
$$
\begin{equation}
d'Q'=K(x'-x)d'x'
\end{equation}
$$

where $K$ is a constant, I need to show that

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{d'Q}{dt}+\frac{d'Q'}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{K}{2}\left(x-x'\right)^{2}\right]
\end{equation}
$$

How can I do so?

**Attempt:**

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(d'Q+d'Q'\right) & =K\frac{d}{dt}\left[(x-x')d'x+(x'-x)d'x'\right]\\
 & =K\left[(x-x')\frac{d}{dt}\left(d'x\right)+d'x\frac{d}{dt}(x-x')\right.\\
 & \qquad\left.(x'-x)\frac{d}{dt}\left(d'x'\right)+d'x'\frac{d}{dt}(x'-x)\right]\\
 & =K\left[(x-x')\frac{d}{dt}\left(d'x-d'x'\right)+\left(d'x-d'x'\right)\frac{d}{dt}(x-x')\right]\\
 & =?
\end{array}
$$

Comment: What is $d'$?..

Comment: I am sorry, but as long as you cannot explain the symbols you use, it is not possible to help you.

Comment: @amsmath Ok, it's meant to represent an infinitesimal. From mathworld: "An infinitesimal is some quantity that is explicitly nonzero and yet smaller in absolute value than any real quantity".

Comment: So, $d'Q$ is the same as $dQ$?

Comment: @amsmath $d'Q$ is in the context of thermodynamics usually called a differential; here in particular it means the average heat transferred over some stochastic process between $t$ and $t+dt$.

Comment: @amsmath Also, it has a prime to mean it is not an exact differential. I agree the notation is not the best one, but that's the one given by this book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In formal terms (I set $K=1$ and $d' = d$),
\begin{align*}
\frac 1 2\frac d{dt}(x-x')^2
&= (x-x')\left(\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{dx'}{dt}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{dt}\big((x-x')dx + (x'-x)dx'\big)\\
&= \frac{1}{dt}(dQ+dQ').
\end{align*}

Comment: I tried that before but I was unsure if it was on good grounds to work the infinitesimals with such freedom... Since you have more of a formal knowledge maybe you can assure me it is?

Comment: Since it's physics, it is. ;-)

Comment: -_- ... Thanks!